# I am not able to pass parameter in api in reacts js

Tags: reactjs

When i click button after entering city and country in input textbox.
then in alert value is coming. but in api it is not passing. when i check in developer tool of browser in console then error shows.

```
[[PromiseValue]]: Object
cod: "404"
message: "city not found"
__proto__: Object
```

```
const App_key = "bbf6d56707d9126ae929a951187fca66"; 

const city = e.target.elements.city.value;

const country = e.target.elements.country.value;

const api_call = await fetch('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city},${country}&APPID=bbf6d56707d9126ae929a951187fca66');
```

Comment: What are the values of const city and const country?

Comment: Try writing const queryString = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city},${country}&APPID=bbf6d56707d9126ae929a951187fca66'; then console.log(queryString), this will probably help with your debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use template literal expressions without the backticks...
Change

```
const api_call = await fetch('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city},${country}&APPID=bbf6d56707d9126ae929a951187fca66');
```

to this

```
const api_call = await fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city},${country}&APPID=bbf6d56707d9126ae929a951187fca66`);
```

Replace '' with ``